# React-native Realm fails to build on IOS

Tags: react-native, realm

Realm version 3.6.0

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "realm": "^3.6.0"
  },
```

This is the error am getting from the build console

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Macintosh'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```